# Component hitting redirect before useEffect is finished

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a `useEffect` setup to run a fetch on an endpoint, and depending on the data it fetches back, I want to either display my component or redirect elsewhere.

The issue I am finding is that the code is running through before my useEffect has completed, so I am always being redirect...

Is there something else I can do to get the desired effect?

**Pseudocode**

```
const myComp = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        /* 
         * I will do my API call here which will set my 
         * variables 'isLoading' and 'myLoadedConditional' via redux
        */
    }, []);

    if (isLoading) return <h1>Still loading</h1>

    return myLoadedConditional
        ? <MyComponent />
        : <Redirect to={`/some-link`} />
}
```

Comment: Do you see "still loading" text during the initial render? Please show the initial and final values of `isLoading` and `myLoadedConditional`. Also make sure that initial value of `isLoading` is true,

Comment: Could you show how you make an API call? Are you using redux thunk which sets loading to false when completed ? From the above code it is not very clear where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

useEffect is run AFTER render, so with your current code if myLoadedConditional is false then it will always use Redirect component

Comment: During the initial render, i assume `if (isLoading)` condition evaluates to true and returns the JSX: `<h1>Still loading</h1>`. Your answer will be correct if the initial value of `isLoading` is not true.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a local `loading state` which is set to `true` by default and then call your api calls and check for `isLoading` and `myLoadedConditional` or set them